# No method XMLEventFactory.newFactory() while making Groovy Script to read .xlsx files on IntelliJ IDEA with JDK 1.8

Tags: java, groovy, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I'm trying to make a groovy script that reads certain .xlsx files and parses them. I want to use Apache POI but I run into several problems. If I try to run the script from IntelliJ IDEA on Mac OS X with a JDK 1.8, with a 3.11 POI @Grab annotation (previous versions won't download because of problems with the xml-apis dependency), this is what happens:

```
Caught: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 

javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;
```

However, the same code in console throws:

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTExtensionList
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTExtensionList
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTExtensionList
```

This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

@Grapes([
        @Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi', version='3.11'),
        @Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi-ooxml', version='3.11'),
        @Grab(group='org.apache.poi', module='poi-ooxml-schemas', version='3.11')
])
    def path = args[0]
    File file = new File(path)

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file)
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0)
    println sheet.getRow(2).getCell(2).getStringCellValue()
```

Where could the problem be?

Comment: The [Apache POI FAQ page](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html) looks to have entries for both your errors, did you try the advice given there?

Comment: I was more focused on fixing the problem within the IDE, but I've decided to give up and work with the terminal. That problem was fixed by changing the schemas dependency to ooxml-schemas-1.1, as recommended in the FAQ, I hadn't read it carefully enough. Answer that if you'd like as that solved one issue.